# client_secret should not be passed to /oauth/token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

Is there any reference available to connect to Facebook using Oauth2 gem in Rails 4?
I am getting above error while calling get_token method of Oauth2.

```
def login_facebook
    redirect_to client.auth_code.authorize_url(
                    :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/facebook_callback'
                )
end

def facebook_callback

    token = client.auth_code.get_token(
                params[:code],
                :token_url => "/oauth/token",
                #:token_url => "/oauth/access_token",
                # :parse => :query,
                :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/facebook_callback'
            )

    puts "**************"
    puts token.inspect
    puts "**************"

end

private
def client
    OAuth2::Client.new(APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, :site => FB_GRAPH_URL)
end
```

Comment: Koala: https://github.com/arsduo/koala    What's the version of your `oauth2` gem ?

Answer (score 0):

The default url for requesting the access token has been changed from `/oauth/access` (which is what FB uses) to `/oauth/access_token`. Now, you need to override this setting as:

```
OAuth2::Client.new(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET, {
  :token_url => '/oauth/access_token',
  :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/facebook_callback'
})
```

You may want to use [Koala](http://github.com/arsduo/koala) gem for easy communication with facebook.